# AWS websocket API using prue Javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, websocket

I need to connect and get data from websocket api build in AWS using api getway.
I used two approach but getting connection error.

```
let socket = new WebSocket("wss://xxxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/demo");

socket.onopen = function(e) {
console.log("[Open] Connection established ... ");
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  console.log(error);
};
```

reference taken - **https://javascript.info/websocket**

both is not working if I put the different url in first then code is working

Testing env - local and jsfiddle

second approach -

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let apiGatewayManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
  apiVersion: '2023-07-29',
  endpoint: 'https://xxxxx.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/demo/',
  region: 'eu-west-2'
});
const params = {
  ConnectionId: 'YYYYYYYYYYYYY',
  Data: 'test'
};
apiGatewayManagementApi.postToConnection(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  } else {
    console.log(data);           // successful response
  }
});
```